# Discrepancy between Histogram and SmoothHistogram

Tags: histograms

```
(* This generates the data that illustrates the issue *)
pdf = MixtureDistribution[{0.54, 0.46}, {CauchyDistribution[0.47, 0.26], NormalDistribution[30.33, 12.04]}]
mock = RandomVariate[pdf, 70000];
mock2 = Select[mock, 0 < # < 50 &];
```

---

When I draw the `Histogram` and `SmoothHistogram`, the two distributions do not align:

```
Histogram[mock2, Automatic, "PDF", PlotRange -> {0, 0.025}];
SmoothHistogram[mock2, "Scott", PlotRange -> {0, 0.025}, PlotStyle -> Red, MaxExtraBandwidths -> {0, 0}];
Show[%%, %]
```

[image]

Based on the docs of [`SmoothHistogram`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SmoothHistogram.html) (Properties & Relations) I'd expect an alignment.

Why is it poor, and how to make it better?

Comment: Removing the `MaxExtraBandwidths` option improves the matching considerably(this goes back to the default extra bandwidths, which is 12).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The distribution function specification in the [`SmoothHistogram`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SmoothHistogram.html) should be "PDF"

```
Clear["Global`*"]

$Version

(* "12.3.1 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (June 19, 2021)" *)

SeedRandom[1234];

dist = MixtureDistribution[{0.54, 0.46}, {CauchyDistribution[0.47, 0.26], 
    NormalDistribution[30.33, 12.04]}];
mock = RandomVariate[dist, 70000];
mock2 = Select[mock, 0 < # < 50 &];

Show[
 Histogram[mock2, Automatic, "PDF", PlotRange -> {0, 0.025}],
 SmoothHistogram[mock2, "Scott", "PDF",
  PlotStyle -> Red,
  PlotRange -> {0, 0.025}]]
```

[image]

Comment: Bob, plotting the PDF is already the default for `SmoothHistogram`. I think what made the difference is the fact that you removed the non-standard value for the `MaxExtraBandwidths` option that was in the original code.